# Is there a MNE Python function that can enable me to use only part of the EEG data?

Tags: python, mne-python

I currently have an EEG.set file with data from 40 minutes of measurement. I only need 20 minutes (from somewhere in the middle) of which I know the starting and ending timestamps. Is there a function within the MNE package so I can select the part of the data that I'll need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mne has a crop function to cut the eeg signal between your desire timestamps. You apply it to your raw data.

https://mne.tools/stable/generated/mne.io.Raw.html#mne.io.Raw.crop

```
tmin = 10
tmax = 30
raw.crop(tmin=tmin, tmax=tmax)
```